# TortoiseGit not showing icon overlays

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have been using `TortoiseGit` for almost a full year now. It has been working very well for me until yesterday, when I encountered a problem. I was deleting a folder when Windows Explorer sort of crashed on me (it hung on "discovering items") for over an hour, then I restarted the system.

Since that time (and I am *not* sure if the incident described has anything to do with it), TortoiseGit has stopped showing icon overlays in explorer. The behaviour is, however, not like any of the others who posted questions here, because:

> In the `open file` dialogue of all programs, the icons still exist (!).

Here is a list of things I tried:

1. I changed TortoiseGit settings to show different icons.
2. Reinstall TortoiseGit (uninstall, restart, install, restart).
3. I deleted all icon overlays starting with "Tortoise" in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer 
   \ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`, then uninstalled TortoiseGit, restarted the computer and reinstalled TortoiseGit.

---

**Edit:**

I tried to create a new user on my computer, and the new user has icon overlays working just fine. I am now even more confused.

Nothing helped so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have TortoiseSVN installed?

Comment: @mozgow No, only TortoiseGit

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Mine happened because I installed "Dropbox" on my machine.  Dropbox also uses IconOverlays, and they rank higher in the list than TortoiseGit.  And since you can only have 15, you might not be seeing them for that reason.  Mine start in the list from 19-28, hence my reason for not seeing them.  Use Dzhuang's suggestion below to see where your Overlays rank in the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TortoiseGit Icon Overlays not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588130/tortoisegit-icon-overlays-not-showing)

Comment: @MrTux I'd be curios to know how you consider a question asked August 6 2014 as a duplicate of a question that was asked January 11 2017 (i.e., over 2 years **later**).

Comment: @5xum I wanted to link both questions and found the newer one better.

Comment: Thanks this really helped me; I found that OneDrive was taking up a bunch of slots that bumped Tortoise out.

Comment: OneDrive is also doing this, current leader has 4 spaces infront

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I had the same problem and I got it to work by following instructions from a forum.  What I did was this (copied):

> I find solution :)
> Wrapping with `""` all tortoise keys under  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`

> on `1TortoiseNormal` and etc...
> I understood the problem, seeing as Dropbox and it worked regedit there was the sign (`""`) to Dropbox but not tortoise.
> So I added the signs, close explorer.exe and hop it was good :)

So what I did was rename the key `1TortoiseNormal` to `"1TortoiseNormal"` etc. I have no idea why wrapping it inside a double quote makes it work again. Note that a restart of Windows Explorer is required for the changes to take effect.

The original forum is gone, but [a good summary](http://garethjmsaunders.co.uk/2015/03/22/managing-overlay-icons-for-dropbox-and-tortoisesvn-and-tortoisegit) is supplied in the comments.

Comment: It is probably a matter of sorting. The double-quote character is one of the first printable characters, so "DropboxExt1" comes before 1TortoiseNormal, but "1TortoiseNormal" comes before "DropboxExt1". I also tried removing the double-quote from the Dropbox's keys and it worked.

Comment: Learnt something from Skype entries. Instead of wrapping it around "" (double-quotes) just add a space at the start of the entries. So the entries would be <space-char>1TortoiseNormal and etc ... It is finally a matter of sorting :) it seems.

Comment: I also had the same problem after installing dropbox.  I found the reason / workaround in this blog clear, however after renaming the tortoise keys they didn't appear to resort to the top of the list .. It took me a little while to realise that the dropbox keys had a space at the front .. so I renamed the tortoise ones to <space>1TortoiseNormal, etc.  BLOG:  http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/2015/03/22/managing-overlay-icons-for-dropbox-and-tortoisesvn-and-tortoisegit/

Comment: @CodyStott It turns out MS is now doing the same... OneDrive icons start with a space as well... In 10 years time after all companies figure out this trick, all key names will start with dozens of spaces... :p

Comment: After making the changes, restarting explorer did the trick (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC->details->end task [explorer], then [new task] explorer)

Comment: Great trick! Worked, however now the annoying thing is that dropbox and onedrive don't show any icons on folders. Any way to have git show the correct items and and dropbox and onedrive as well?

Comment: Just looked in my registry and the OneDrive keys have three spaces in front of them, followed by GoogleDrive and Tortoise having two spaces in front of them. What a broken implementation!

Comment: And furthermore, when I removed the spaces in front of OneDrive and relogged into the computer, OneDrive complained it needed permission to finish installing an update. After granting that permission, the registry entries with thee spaces returned! Apparently it looks at these entries to determine if the installation is complete. PIA!

Comment: Long discussion: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2548

I wonder how long it would take for programs to actually COUNT spaces there and dynamically allocate "one more space"

Comment: UPDATE: Dropbox now also adds *3* spaces in front... MS please take note (well you already did as OneDrive is using this trick) and **take action**. This completely sucks. And what's up with this 11/15 icon maximum anyway? It's 2017?!? I don't need yet another UI overhaul... I need stuff like this to get fixed in under 2 decades!

Comment: FYI, programs like Onedrive, Google Drive, Dropbox, Mega, etc. all insist now on installing in some cases ludicrious numbers of overlays.  Unfortunatenly, TortoiseGit is at the top of that list of the worst.  The root cause is that there is a hard coded friggin limit of like 15 so it is physically IMPOSSIBLE for even a COUPLE of these providers to have their overlays work it's the dumbest thing even in WIN10 it's still not fixed!! They all now DETECT when they've been "bumped" and answer by doing what WE DO which is to add leading spaces etc. so it's an endless battle of the overlays!  LOL

Comment: @CollinChaffin So that brings us to the question: What character comes BEFORE space that we can use as registry key prefix to beat the game?

Comment: I added the " ", make sure that TortoiseGIT comes first in sorting, and restart explorer.exe. However, icon overlay is still not showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: As of July 2020, GoogleDrive is in the lead with 4 spaces, Dropbox at 3, Tortoise at 2, OneDrive at 1. 

Instead of trying to find something that will sort before space, has anyone tried removing spaces from entries that are taking precedence?

Comment: @S.Stromberg I think they fight back on startup (by putting more spaces). So I'm not sure if there is a way other than writing your own script that runs on startup and fix the sort as intended.

Comment: ASCII sort order chart: http://support.ecisolutions.com/doc-ddms/help/reportsmenu/ascii_sort_order_chart.htm

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. Deleting the OneDrive icons from the registry and a reboot fixed the problem. Dream team.

Comment: This worked for me under Windows 11 with five leading spaces *before* the quotation marks. Add more spaces on demand to make it the top entry.

Comment: Nice GUI tool: https://github.com/larspehrsson/ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers/releases

Comment: Also vote for [support of the new "Status" Column in Explorer](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/3795).

Answer (score 138):

Windows will only allow up to 11 icon overlay identifiers, arranged in alphanumeric order - if there are more than 11, these icons will not be displayed.

You can run the following command in a DOS prompt:

`regedit /e c:\icons.txt HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`

Then open the file `C:\icons.txt`. Skip the first two lines, and if `1TortoiseNormal` and the other `*Tortoise*` values are not in the top 11 values, their icon overlays will not be shown. The solution provided by [@Chi Chan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26534509/327074) is just a simple way to make `1TortoiseNormal` rank higher when ordered among all the overlays, you can also rename the values by adding space(s) before `1TortoiseNormal`, i.e.,

`"    1TortoiseNormal"`

to make them rank higher.

**update:**  for Windows 8, the limit of icon overlays is 15.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helping for me. I have removed entries in `ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` so that `*Tortoise*` is the first nine, and rebooted. There are considerably more than 15 entries, but Tortoise is first

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Do you mean use the shell command to generate the txt? If `Tortoise` displayed in the beginning 15 entries, there should be no problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use the shell command to generate the txt". `Tortoise` is in the beginning of the entries, but there are more than 15 entries total.

Comment: LOL. So I just upgraded to Windows 10 and my TortoiseGit icons were missing so I searched and found this thread... Turns out that Microsoft probably also read this thread because the OneDrive icons start with a space by default!!  How silly of Microsoft that they would resort to that... instead of just building a screen that lets us configure the order / priority of the icon annotations from within Windows settings.

Comment: +1 because of the smart command... Inside regedit itself it's hard to see the order in which Windows picks up the keys.

Comment: It looks like the limit for Windows 10 is 10 icons.

Comment: Your explaination on why and how was the best man! Saved my day. To the top with you

Comment: @StijndeWitt GoogleDrive and TortoiseSVN/Git now seem to have upped the ante and added **2** spaces. We're officially in a space race now...

Comment: @icc97 LOL@'space race'. But DropBox is one step ahead of these amateurs... they add **3** spaces: `[....\   DropboxExt01]` (edit: SO collapses them into 1 it seems...)

Comment: Great explanation, my issue was caused by DropBox spaces... Added two more spaces before Tortoise icons and this worked great! No way to increase icon overlay max, right? What if I'd like to use correctly both dropbox and tortoise?

Comment: @LucaMus maybe you can check  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4411336/3437454 to find the answer

Comment: NOTE!! Restart Windows Explorer for the icons to show up. Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc and restart "Windows Explorer" (Optionally restart computer)

Comment: I just commented above too but wanted to add here that all the big cloud providers (onedrive, dropbox, google drive) now DYNAMICALLY read the list and will AUTOMATICALLY ADAPT and tleading spaces to "win" the war....until the next one updates and does the same.  Mine now have literally all at least FIVE leading spaces!!  Also, it's 15 from Vista and later.

Comment: @Collin: I can confirm, just found that OneDrive has 4 leading spaces already on my system (Windows 10). What a ...

Comment: Why in the world does Windows limit the number of icon overlay extensions?

Comment: Worked like a charm on Windows 10 x64! Thank you!

Comment: @StijndeWitt it's ok, few years later TortoiseGit found the right fix for this: all it's icons start with TWO spaces! :)

Answer (score 55):

Windows 10 Solution Steps;

1. Open regedit

Path :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers

2. Remove/delete all SkyDrive/OneDrive keys. You may need to take ownership of the keys one by one and give your user full control if you receive an error while trying to delete the keys.
3. Press Ctrl+Shift+Esc and restart "Windows Explorer" (Optionally restart computer)
4. All git/svn overlay icons are now visible !

Comment: This works for me. It seems there is a limit to the number of icon overlays allowed on windows explorer.

Comment: For whatever reason I couldn't delete OneDrive keys. I just added three spaces to the start of Tortoise keys, rebooted and it worked again.

Comment: OneDrive puts the keys back in the next time you relog.

Comment: Instead of deleting existing keys you can just add two (or more) spaces in front of all *Tortoise* keys. Will have the same effect - and let you join the space race!

Comment: This solution works for me. Delete all the onedrive keys and then restart PC, wow, the overlay icons appear!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.  Didn't have a problem with OneDrive keys.

Comment: It is a race for a space (or several)!

Answer (score 22):

Just add one Space(or more if needed) to first Name of Tortoise options to this regedit addersses:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers
```

for example:

```
"1TortoiseNormal"
```

Should change to:

```
" 1TortoiseNormal"
```

after a system `reboot` icons shows currectly.

Answer (score 10):

I had installed TortoiseSVN (1.9.5) and msysgit (2.11.0) first on my Windows 10 64-bit machine. TortoiseSVN icons displayed fine.

When I installed TortoiseGit (2.3.0.0) after these two the icons wouldn't display.

I checked `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` and all looked fine. The tortoise icons were in the top 10.

What I used to fix was raised in [TortoiseGit issue #692 on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/692#note_1774150):

> - Open `regedit.exe`
>
>   - Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
>   - Add a new string value "Max Cached Icons" with value "2000"
>
> closed/restarted explorer and icons display!

Comment: I found this to be the easiest, fastest and best solution for me (Windows 10).

Comment: This also worked for me.  I'd added 5 spaces to all Tortoise entries in the registry then restarted Explorer but didn't work till I tried this answer as well.

Comment: worked like charm

Answer (score 6):

Open `regedit`.

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\`

You will see some thing like this:

> [image]

The order is important, and in above example the `Dropbox` is above `Tortoise`, which is the cause of this issue.

To fix this I've add one more space charter to `Tortoise`. You can do what ever you like to move it to the top. So change    `Tortoise1Normal` to     `Tortoise1Normal`.( I suspired when I see that the    `Tortoise1Normal` has many spaces. The guys at `tortoises` thought that these many spaces make them top in registry !! While `dropbox` guys beat them as    `DropBox` has high order than    `Tortoise1Normal`. )

The `registry` will be some thing like this: ( You need to close and reopen `regiedit` or press `F5` to see new sorting)

> [image]

---

Finally `End Task` the `explorer` and re run it.

Comment: I remember doing this years ago, and it seems it's still the same today (2023). Ended up changing the two spaces before each Tortoise key to four spaces, restarted explorer and bam! Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: You have to remove write permission for SYSTEM from the parent key by taking ownership

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem today after uninstalling TortoiseSVN. I rebooted and still no luck so I just went into **Control Panel, Uninstall a Program and on the TortoiseGit item I picked 'Repair'** and everything is back to normal. I suspect that all of the Tortoise line of apps have some shared registry keys or something.

Answer (score 3):

I also had my TortoiseGIT shell icons quit displaying suddenly, I don't remember exactly what led up to it but I found this and tried the registry stuff changing 1TortioiseNormal to "1TortioiseNormal" and so on. That is probably a good thing to do no matter what but icon overlays were still not working.

I am too busy for the blanket answer of "restart the computer" what that says to me is "some service process needs to be restarted but you'd never be able to find it so just restart." Nah.

I also use TortoiseSVN and those icon overlays were still working for me. I looked in my processes tab of task manager and saw I had something called TSVNCache.exe running. No sign of anything similar for git, so on a whim I went over to the applications tab and hit "New Task", entered TGITCache.exe and sure enough that process fired up. From there go back to processes, kill explorer.exe, then go back to applications -> New Task again and fire up explorer.exe.

This has worked for me twice now when my TortoiseGIT icon overlays have quit, so, maybe it will work for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to uninstall Google Drive from my computer. Not sure why yet.

Comment: See my comments above.  There is hard coded limit of 15 overlays and Google Drive uses several as does Onedrive, dropbox, and others.  Torroise is one of worse using like 10 all by itself leaving almost none for anything else.  By removing Google Drive you simply deleted it's overlay reg keys leaving enough "free" of the 15 to finally see the Tortoise icons.

Answer (score 2):

I Agree with Chi Chan and I would like to add this as an complementary answer.

It's Dropbox Explorer icons. Here is a registry script to remove them. Save it somewhere, because they will come back!

*Note, that the values change from time to time, too. Currently they have 3 spaces before the "DropboxExtXX", before they had only one.*

#### Remove Dropbox Explorer Icons.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt01]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt02]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt03]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt04]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt05]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt06]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt07]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt08]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt09]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\   DropboxExt10]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the leading spaces is that every time you reboot, Dropbox adds another space to its registries, and will be always one step ahead of you.

So I've scheduled a python script found on this [post](https://cito.github.io/blog/overlay-icon-battle/) (by Christoph Zwerschke) to execute every time the computer boots. You also have to restart the Explorer after that.

The .bat will look like:

```
python iconOverlayFixer.py
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe 
start explorer.exe
```

And the python script:

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import os
import winreg as reg

# names of all overlay icons that shall be boosted:

boost = """
    Tortoise1Normal
    Tortoise2Modified
    Tortoise3Conflict
    Tortoise4Locked
    Tortoise5ReadOnly
    Tortoise6Deleted
    Tortoise7Added
    Tortoise8Ignored
    Tortoise9Unversioned
"""

boost = set(boost.split())

with reg.OpenKey(reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion'
        r'\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers') as base:

    names = set()
    renames = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            name = reg.EnumKey(base, i)
        except OSError:
            break
        core = name.strip()
        if core in names:
            print('Delete', repr(core))
            reg.DeleteKey(base, name)
        else:
            names.add(core)
            if core in boost:
                core = ' ' + core
            if core != name:
                renames.append((name, core))
        i += 1

    if renames:
        for old_name, new_name in renames:
            print('Rename', repr(old_name), 'to', repr(new_name))
            value = reg.QueryValue(base, old_name)
            reg.CreateKey(base, new_name)
            reg.SetValue(base, new_name, reg.REG_SZ, value)
            reg.DeleteKey(base, old_name)
    else:
        print('Nothing to rename')
```

Answer (score 1):

What is worked for me for Windows 10 is

1. uninstalling TortoiseGit
2. cleaning folders and register
3. installing it once again
4. rebooting the computer
5. making random commit even not seeing the red icon

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that overlay was managed by TortoiseSVN shell extention. This can be verified using [nirsoft ShellEx View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html). The overlay icons disappears when I disable TortoiseSVN extensions. They apparead back when I re-enable TortoiseSVN (the blue lines in screenshot below)

[image]

In ShellEx View, select `Options > Filter By Extension Type`. Select `System` in dialog and clic `OK`. Then you should the TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN extensions. Make sure all TortoiseSVN entries are enabled.

I hope the may be useful to anyone else.

Comment: By far that was the best option I've tested. When disabling an extension using the tool, at least for the "more than intrusive" OneDrive and Google Drive wil stop stealing the overlays. Auto-updates released thereafter will not harm your settings.

Answer (score 1):

For me (using Windows 10), after I install `tortoise git`, restarting windows explorer in TaskManager solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go To "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers"

Prefix all the Tortoise*** folders with 5 White Spaces(Spacebars) - You may find Tortoise1*** to Tortoise9*** folders

Close the registry window and restart your PC.

It worked for me, i hope it works for others too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Exported registry file, opened in text editor and deleted leading spaces. Added exclamation (!) to front of Tortoise. Saved as Preferred-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Settings.reg
2. Wrote batch file to delete key and subkeys then restore from *.reg file.
3. Can run at any time, place in startup folder or write as powershell and place in task scheduler to run upon startup.

batch file:

```
REG DELETE HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers /F
TIMEOUT 1 > NUL
REG IMPORT "H:\GIT\Preferred-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Settings.reg"
```

reg file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\!Tortoise8Ignored]
@="{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\GoogleDriveSynced]
@="{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\DropboxExt01]
@="{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case following worked -
Go to TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Icon Overlays -> CHECK THE OPTION - Drives A and B
and then overlay icons appears without restarting PC

**Note:** I also uninstalled one drive but I don't think that has any contribution to the solution, you can try that also.