# Git red and green status icon disappear in file folder

Tags: git, tortoisegit

After I modified my files under git folder, the modified files cannot show red icon. Also, the green status also disappears. I do not know how to restore the normal status color of the changed/commited files. I use tortoiseGit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably Tortoise's explorer plugin crashed again. Happens all the time. Try killing explorer.exe process and restarting it (desktop will disappear! don't worry, as long as you have a way to run explorer.exe again! keep calm and watch out, have a console window open, or whatever, so you can start explorer.exe again). Might help. Otherwise, well, that instability and constant problems were one of the reasons I stopped using TortoiseSvn/TortoiseGit and switched to and got used to normal commandline git tools + minimalistic git-extensions suite for Windows.

Comment: Solved my problem by this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31914490/7700513

Answer (score 0):

In case of crash, as commented, try and open the same folder in [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)

The last 1.55 VSCode (March 2021) has [decoration enabled by default (including on tabs)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55#_tab-decorations-on-by-default), and you will be able to check if those files are still properly managed.

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_55/tabs-deco.png]