# TortoiseGit overlay icon is red but all files are commited

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I committed all of my files and my commit list in TortoiseGit is empty but some of my folders are red.

- I killed TGitCache.exe from task manager, but nothing happened.
- I renamed my folder (by adding a number at the end of folder name) and reverting back to main name and problem still remains.
- And finally, I did this workaround (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42757933/3428078) but it did not work for me.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible that some files changed their name only in case.

Normal `git status` operations don't show this (, but git itself is case sensitive even if core.ignorecase=true on Windows).

This behavior of TortoiseGit changed in 2.5.0, see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/releasenotes/#Release_2.5.0.0:

> Since TortoiseGit 2.5.0 the icon overlays are case sensitive. if you really want to change this default, you can disable the advanced setting "OverlaysCaseSensitive". This is, however, not the default and not recommended as some git tools such as "git log" are case sensitive on paths and might show an incomplete history.

Comment: I was in this situation and to figure out which files were duplicated, I ran the following command in git bash on Windows:
 `git ls-files | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq -cd`