# TortoiseGit does not show overlay icons for some files - sometimes

Tags: tortoisegit

I currently have a very strange issue. I have a repository, which includes another one as submodule. Recently, I added some files (three to be exact) within a subfolder of that submodule. I did that via git cli and not with TortoiseGit. Everything worked fine and the files show up correctly at the remote.

But in the Windows Explorer I was missing the overlay icons for the files as well as for the subfolder.

I started playing around. When I changed a file, the red overlay icon appeared. And it stayed there even after refreshing the explorer view. When reverting it back, the file got its green overlay icon. But when refreshing the explorer view or navigating around, the green icon disappeared.

So as the overlay icons are generally working (for all other files in all my repositories as well as sometimes for the files in question) it is not related to the typical icon overlay issue with too many programs claiming them as in [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588130/tortoisegit-icon-overlays-not-showing)].

I clone a new copy of my repo. All files are there and the icons work as they should.

I also checked the casing of my file names and folders as suggested by [[2](https://superuser.com/questions/1434092/tortoisegit-overlay-icon-missing-from-a-single-versioned-file)]. I did not spot any issues there.

I dug around more and tried the two answers [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42757933/5223273)] and [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37722092/5223273)] to a similar question. [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42757933/5223273)] did have no effect. Surprisingly [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37722092/5223273)] worked as long as the parent directory was renamed. As soon as I changed the name back to the original name I was back to the original non working behavior.

So here I am, without any clue what this could be. I know I could solve my problem with a new clone or with renaming of the folder. But I would like to understand the root cause. Because either I did something wrong in my process and probably should change it, or there is a bug in TortoiseGit, TGitCache or something like that, which maybe could be fixed.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It appears that this just might have been a hiccup of git. It resolved kind of itself in the meanwhile.

Comment: I was haunted with this for quite a while. Some specific files, for example, resource.h, after update do not show any icon overlays, although the underlying git seems to treat them correctly, I can commit (OK), and it still shows no overlay, and a folder shows 'modified'. "Diff" says it is all right (??). To fix, I have to remove file, and revert. All will be well until the next file update. Similarly named files on similar projects behave correctly.

Comment: "Haunted" is most likely the best description ;-) I have never since experienced the issue. So I do not have a clue what it was. It automagically resolved at some point.